# Auto-increment readable number MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, controller

For the primary key in this model, I use a guid but we wanted something that is human readable in case someone wanted to refer to it - so I created a ticketNumber field.  I need to get this field to autoincrement and here is the code I have:

```
ticket.TicketNumber = db.Tickets.Max(t => t.TicketNumber) + 1;
```

It is not crashing but it is not working either.  All the ticket numbers are coming out as 0.

Comment: Lets start with design of your table...

Comment: Do you need the whole table design? TicketNumber is an Int.  What else do you need?

Comment: you said, "For the primary key in this model, I use a guid ...". Why? What is motivation behind it? Why not `pkField int not null identity` ?

Comment: My boss told me to use Guid for the primary key for all my tables and then have a separate field for people to be able to say open ticket# 423, etc.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using entity framework code first? or database first?

Comment: I am using code first

Comment: Just declare the `TicketNumber` field to be an `identity` field, it doesn't have to be part of your primary key at all; then once you insert a record into the table, you have a unique integer Ticket number.

Comment: @StephenByrne,

I already have this code there `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`  

and it is still coming out as 0 for every one.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @djblois - but is the actual column in the database schema declared as `identity`? `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` just tells EF to expect that it is and read the value back whenever a record is inserted; if the actual column isn't `identity` you'll always get 0.